# How to replace value with another by condtion in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have the following df:

| ICB | sICB |
| --- | --- |
| A | B1 |
| ZB1 | ZC1 |
| ZB1 | ZC2 |
| ZB1 | ZC3 |

For each row, I want to replace `ZB1` with the value in the column `sICB`.

All other related answers on SO are referring to "some other value" as part of a condition. But I need to replace any occurrence of `ZB1` with whatever is in the `sICB` column. There must be a simple way to do it, but I can't come up with it.

I've tried with `df[loc]` with `DataFrame.replace()`, `mask`, `where`.

What intuitively seems correct is:

`df.where([df['ICB'].eq('ZB1'), df[sICB])`

Comment: `df.loc[df['ICB'], eq('ZB1'), 'ICB'] = df['sICB']` or `m = df['ICB'], eq('ZB1') ; df.loc[m, 'ICB'] = df.loc[m, 'sICB']`

Comment: Can also do `df['ICB'] = np.where([df['ICB'].eq('ZB1'), df[sICB], df['ICB'])`